# The mappedName is always the same across application servers?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jndi, application-server

I have a stateless bean with some properties:

1. It's a EJB3
2. class AddressFacade
3. implements AddressFacadeRemote
4. it's inside a ejb-jar (MyJAR.jar)
5. it's in a EAR (MyEAR).

My application server (Weblogic) generated this name (jndiName/mappedName):

```
MyEARMyJAR_jarAddressFacade_AddressFacadeRemote
```

I can't use injection, so I'll make a lookup with this name.

The question is: *this name always will be the same if I maintain the same EAR,JAR,Class and interface name? Or it can change from application servers?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is: this name always will be the same if I maintain the same EAR,JAR,Class and interface name? Or it can change from application servers?

JNDI names are not standardized in Java EE 5 and will change from one application server to the other. Adam Bien wrote a nice post illustrating this:

> #### [EJB 3 Portability Issue: why JNDI names are not standardized?](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/ejb_3_portability_issue_why)
>
> As I mentioned in my previous post, 
>   the portability of Java EE 5
>   applications is much better, than in
>   the old J2EE 1.4 world. I found one
>   issue, which causes some effort - the
>   lack of defined and unified
>   JNDI-Naming and addressing. The
>   glassfish applicationsserver uses the
>   [fully qualified name](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#SessionBeanGlobalJNDINameAssignment) of the
>   remote business interface as default.
>   The JBoss appserver uses the name of
>   the EJB with the "/remote" ending. So
>   the following Session Bean:
>
> ```
> package com.abien;
>
> @Stateless
> public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorld {
>
>     public String sayHello(String hello){
>         return "Echo from server: ";
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> can be found with JBoss (with EJB3
>   support) using the following
>   code-snippet:
>
> ```
> Context context = new InitialContext();
> HelloWorld helloWorld = (HelloWorld) context.lookup("myEarName/HelloWorldBean/remote");
> ```
>
> and Glassfish (v1 and v2), using the
>   fully qualified name of the
>   remote-business interface:
>
> ```
> Context context = new InitialContext();
> HelloWorld helloWorld = (HelloWorld) context.lookup(HelloWorld.class.getName());
> ```

One decent way to handle this is to use  a `ServiceLocator` and "pluggable" application server specific strategies. Have a look at at [ServiceLocator, JNDI Naming Helper and Java EE 5](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/servicelocator_jndi_naming_helper_and).

In Java EE 6, things are fixed and we finally have [Portable Global JNDI Names](http://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/portable_global_jndi_names).